# struggling to get right xpath for pop up image

Tags: css, xpath, selenium

I'm struggling to write a xpath which will help me finding image for popup.gif above based on known td element name, such as in this case "one" and "two".

Comment: I'm struggling to write a xpath  which will help me finding image for popup.gif above based on known td element name, such as in this case "one" and "two".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question could be answered better with additional context.  However if you are simply looking for the image tag which links to "popup.gif" assuming there is no URL you can use a pretty simple document-wide search:

```
//img[@src="popup.gif"]
```

If you a fully qualified URL or a relative URL not in the same folder is used to link to "popup.gif", and you aren't entirely sure what the URL will be in a given environment, you can use a regular expression match on the string of the `src` attribute.

```
//img[matches(@src, "popup\.gif")]
```

To use the `name` attribute to match, you can also do path-based matches as follows:

```
//td[@name="one"]/img
```

This will match the following structure.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td name="one">
       <img src="...."/>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This expression may be excessively generic, it's highly dependent upon your document structure.

Comment: `matches()` is a XPath 2.0 function. Also, you don't need to escape anything except RegExp' special characters, so `popup\.gif` is enough

Comment: @Alejandr: Thank you for your time taking a look into my issue. I guess I should have post full doc structure to get clear picture. Following is snippet.

Comment: <tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[@id='myid']/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/img</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[@id='myid']/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/img</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

<tr>
 <td>click</td>
 <td>//div[@id='myid']/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[3]/img</td>
 <td></td>
</tr>

Comment: So, based on known tr[index names], such as "one", "two", I want to click on <img src="images/shared/popup.gif" class="popupIndicator">

Comment: @doneright: Please, learn how to ask a question, otherwise you are wasting your and others' time. Ihave voted to `C L O S E` this "question".